# IQueryable<T> first free spot

Tags: c#, linq, collections, iqueryable

What's the most efficient way to get a **first** free spot from sorted query returning **int** collection ?

eg.: {1,2,3,4,6} | result.: 5

At the moment I am using foreach and counter that compares current value from sorted quety.ToList()
which takes about 600ms on 100 000 records.

Comment: You're not doing this to generate IDs, are you?  If you explain more about the scenario, maybe someone can think of an alternate means of achieving the same goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you multithread it, reading one at a time is your fastest solution since this is an O(n) problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you would write it in LINQ, but I suppose a binary search could be faster in this way - starting from the middle, comparing the index with value - if they are equal, continue in the right half, otherwise in the left half etc.

Even if you're starting from an index **start_index** which is not 1, you can simply compare the value with index increased by **start_index**.

Comment: That is if you have the index.

Comment: You have the index = you can access the collection at a concrete index ? If you can't do that then you're probably right that it's O(n) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use ToList()? Turning it to a list renders the whole IEnumerable idea absolute and you might lose some performance there. Why not iterate with foreach over the IQueryable and find the first missing memeber?

Comment: Tryed it , it takes twice as much time.

Comment: Err... It took LESS TIME with ToList()?